# Having issues with execvp()

Tags: c++, fork, execvp

So here is the bit of my code that's giving me problems:

```
void childProcessHandler(string command){


int argCounter = 0;
for(int i=0; i!=command.size(); i++)
    argCounter+=( command.at(i) == ' ');

char * temp, *token;
char *childArgs[argCounter];

argCounter = 1;

temp = new char [command.size()+1];
strcpy (temp, command.c_str());

token = strtok (temp," ");
childArgs[0] = token;

while (token!=NULL)
{
    token = strtok(NULL," ");
    childArgs[argCounter] = token;
    argCounter++;
}
    
//delete[] temp; //Should remove token as well?

execvp(childArgs[0], childArgs);

cout<<"PROBLEM!"<<endl;
exit(-1);

}
```

In the main() method my code gets to a point where it forks() (the parent process then waits for the child to exit.) then the child process (process ID == 0 yes?) calls the method childProcessHandler with the user input (command to run + args) as it's argument. Then I tokenize the user input and call execvp on it.

Everything compiles and executes. The line after execvp is never reached because execvp only returns when there is an error yes?

The project is to simulate a unix terminal however when I give it the command "date" nothing gets printed like it should... The child exits and the parent process resumes just fine however nothing is sent back up to the terminal window...

What am I doing wrong?

(Also we were "recommended" to use strtok to tokenize it but if anyone has anything simpler i'm open to opinions.)

THANKS!

## **EDIT**

The above code works, for example, if I type in "date " instead of "date". I think there might be something fishy with the "tokenizer" not putting a null character at the end of the childArgs[] array. I'll play around with that and thanks for the quick responses!

(Ninja edit, also commented out delete[] temp for the time being)

Comment: You are deleting the array that childArgs refers too.

Comment: Commented out delete[] temp, still no change. It was my understanding that strtok rendered the original string more or less useless after it was run through completly (so why not delete it?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your childargs vector of pointers point into the bytes allocated in the block of memory "temp". When you free temp, you are removing the memory pointed to by the childargs pointers, possibly corrupting some of the values within your vector.

Remove the call to delete[] to stop freeing the memory pointed to by the childargs pointers. You will not be leaking memory. Once you call exec_*() your entire process image is replaced anyway. The only thing that survives a call to exec*_() (for the most part) are your file descriptors.

As a test, try something a bit more simple: After your call to fork() in the child, just call exec with the path to "date". Make that work before fiddling with the parameter list vector.

As another test, remove your call to exec, and print out your entire vector of pointers to make sure that your tokenizing is working the way you think it should. Remember that your final entry must be NULL so that you know where the end of the vector is.

Comment: Final entry was not null. Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing std::string and char/char*. Fine, but you have to be careful, they have different behaviours.

In particular this line:

```
temp = new char [command.size()+1];
```

Is creating an actual array to hold a string in.

```
token = strtok (temp," ");
```

This is making token (which is just a pointer) point to a place inside temp. strtok() modifies the input string to make a temporary string within a string (sounds crazy, I know).

You need to copy the string strtok() gives you into a permanent home. Either use std::string to save you time and code, or do it the char* way and allocate the new string yourself. E.g. instead of:

```
childArgs[0] = token;
```

you need:

```
   childArgs[0] = new char[strlen(token)+1];
   strcpy(childArgs[0], token);
```

The same applies to tokens stored in the array during the loop over the command arguments.

Comment: Thank's for your help. This, unfortunately, did not fix the problem I was having but it was still helpful.

Comment: Are you sure? After making these changes your code works perfectly for me. EDIT: Never mind, I saw the other answer, which is also correct :)